# Are there certain alignments in planetary orbits that create interesting effects in the moons or planets?

Tags: planets, exoplanets

We have some interesting examples such as [Mercury's perihelion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability_of_the_Solar_System#Scenarios)

> The planet Mercury is especially susceptible to Jupiter's influence
>   because of a small celestial coincidence: Mercury's perihelion, the
>   point where it gets closest to the sun, moves around at a rate of
>   about 1.5 degrees every 1000 years, and Jupiter's perihelion moves
>   around only a little slower. One day, the two may fall into sync, at
>   which time Jupiter's constant gravitational tugs could accumulate and
>   pull Mercury off course. This could eject it from the Solar System
>   altogether[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability_of_the_Solar_System#Scenarios) or send it on a collision course with Venus or
>   Earth.[10]

And also the [alignment of Jupiter and Saturn](http://www.quora.com/Are-there-certain-alignments-in-the-solar-systems-orbits-that-create-additional-interesting-effects-on-our-planets-moons-or-sun)

> Yes. When Jupiter and Saturn align, Jupiter's plasma shadow may
>   disrupt magnetospheric activity at Saturn. Jupiter's 1-billion-km
>   plasma shadow (magnetotail) is the largest structure within the Solar
>   System. When Jupiter and Saturn align, Jupiter's plasma shadow can
>   envelop Saturn. Based on Voyager 1 observations, it is plausible - but
>   not proven - that the reduction in solar wind pressure reduces
>   magnetospheric activity around Saturn. This is like drafting an upwind
>   cyclist. http://www.solarviews.com/eng/vg...

But are there any other interesting effects that could be created by other planetary orbit alignments? Especially in exoplantary systems?